# Should I use the production docker build when doing CI to run tests?

Tags: docker, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, composer-php

Should I replicate the production environment (docker image, dependencies, etc) when running tests?

The question is because how do I get composer development packages like phpunit and phpstan if I am replicating the prod environment?

What are best practices regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I replicate the production environment (docker image,
>   dependencies, etc) when running tests?

The immediate answer to this is yes. By replicating the production environment in your test environment means that you can limit issues that only happen in one specific environment biting you in production.

Having said this there are many times where it is not appropriate to make your test environment identical to your production environment. E.g. for a web service you cannot (easily) in CI run your tests against the production domain name.

Docker makes it a lot easier for you to use the production environment in other parts of the SDLC e.g. development and CI. I would advise making the docker image for your production environment available to all working on the project (dev, QA etc.) There will be examples where people want to move away from the production docker image, for example, installing additional debugging tools that should not be available in production.

In summary, using your production docker image (and dependencies) in your test / dev environment will give you greater confidence of how your product will perform in production. This will reduce your time to market and environmental issues in production.

Comment: Thanks, my question was more towards "How do I install composer development packages if I am using the prod image that doesn't install it?"